# I would like to check physical ports redunducy check with python

Tags: python, networking, port, redundancy

1. would like to check physical network ports with python scripts
2. ports information as following, Python scripts can check if ServerID has 2 or more physical network lines to differents network devices.

ServerID,NetworkID,Port name

Server_1,NW_1,ge-0/0/8

Server_2,NW_2,ge-0/0/5

Server_3,NW_3,Ethernet7/15

Server_4,NW4,ae4

Server_4,NW4,ge-2/2/0

Server_4,NW4,ge-2/2/1

Server_4,NW4,ge-2/2/2

Server_4,NW4,ge-2/3/0

Server_4,NW4,ge-2/3/1

Server_10,NW5,ae4

Server_10,NW5,ge-2/2/0

Server_10,NW5,ge-2/2/1

Server_10,NW5,ge-2/2/2

Server_10,NW5,ge-2/3/0

Server_10,NW5,ge-2/3/1

Server_16,NW6,ae5

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/3

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/4

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/5

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/3/2

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/3/3

Server_22,NW7,ae5

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/3

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/4

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/5

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/3/2

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/3/3

Server_28,NW8,ge-8/0/0

Server_28,NW9,ge-8/0/0

Server_30,NW10,ge-0/0/2

Server_30,NW11,ge-0/0/3

Server_32,NW12,ge8

Server_32,NW13,ge-0/0/2

Server_34,NW13,ge-0/0/3

Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/3

Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/4

Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/5

Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/6

Server_35,NW14,port-channel2

Server_35,NW15,xg16

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/3

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/4

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/5

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/6

Server_41,NW16,port-channel2

Server_41,NW17,xg16

Server_16,NW6,ae5

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/3

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/4

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/5

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/3/2

Server_16,NW6,ge-2/3/3
Server_22,NW7,ae5

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/3

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/4

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/5

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/3/2

Server_22,NW7,ge-2/3/3

Server_28,NW8,ge-8/0/0

Server_28,NW9,ge-8/0/0

Server_30,NW10,ge-0/0/2

Server_30,NW11,ge-0/0/3

Server_32,NW12,ge8

Server_32,NW13,ge-0/0/2

Server_34,NW13,ge-0/0/3

Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/3

Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/4

Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/5

Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/6

Server_35,NW14,port-channel2

Server_35,NW15,xg16

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/3

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/4

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/5

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/6

Server_41,NW16,port-channel2

Server_41,NW17,xg16

3. I have already tried with -1)-2) etc. but cannot filter out single-line connected servers.
   -1) df.set_index(['ServerID', 'NetwroID'])
   -2) df.groupby(['ServerID', 'NetwroID'])
4. expected results

=> following servers aren't redundant with more 2 physical lines and network devices.

Server_1,NW_1,ge-0/0/8

Server_2,NW_2,ge-0/0/5

Server_3,NW_3,Ethernet7/15

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/3

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/4

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/5

Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/6

Server_41,NW16,port-channel2

Server_41,NW17,xg16

5. any good idea would be appreciated.

code
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ports_analysis_example.cvs')

df_groupby_1=df.groupby(['Server_ID','Network_ID']).count()

df_groupby_1

I would like to print out redundant problematic servers from following DataFrame.

Server_ID   Network_ID  Port_name

Server_1    NW1 1

Server_10   NW5 6

Server_16   NW6 6

Server_2    NW2 1

Server_22   NW7 6

Server_28   NW8 1   redundant network

```
        NW9 1
```

Server_3    NW3 1

Server_30   NW10    1  redundant network

```
        NW11    1
```

Server_32   NW12    1  redundant network

```
        NW13    1
```

Server_34   NW13    1

Server_35   NW14    5

```
        NW15    1
```

Server_4    NW4     6

Server_41   NW16     5

```
        NW17    1
```

Comment: This looks an awful lot like homework.  You need to show us your code.  This is not a hard task.  pandas has APIs to check for duplicates.

Comment: Why isn't `Server_41,NW14` considered "redundant"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TimRoberts it is not homework. I have 25000 physical network ports information which some of servers are not redundant network connections.

>>Why isn't Server_41,NW14 considered "redundant"? => because it doesn't have same number of connections which NW15 has. 

physical connections should same numbers of physical lines which has connected to same numbers of network devices.

Comment: import pandas as pd  </br>
df = pd.read_csv('ports_analysis_example.cvs')  

df_groupby_1=df.groupby(['Server_ID','Network_ID']).count()  

df_groupby_1  

  Port_name
Server_ID Network_ID 
Server_1 NW1 1
Server_10 NW5 6
Server_16 NW6 6
Server_2 NW2 1
Server_22 NW7 6
Server_28 NW8 1
                NW9 1
Server_3 NW3 1
Server_30 NW10 1  redundant network
               NW11 1
Server_32 NW12 1
                NW13 1
Server_34 NW13 1
Server_35 NW14 5
              NW15 1
Server_4 NW4 6
Server_41 NW16 5
                NW17 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

import csv 

df = pd.read_csv('all_port_connections_informaion_0819_csv.csv', encoding = 'cp949')

ports_analysis=df.set_index(['connected_serverID','serverID','ports'], drop=False)

csv_data=open('all_port_connections_informaion_0819_csv.csv')

data=csv.reader(csv_data)

nets = {}

k_list = []

print(k_list)

for line in data:

    key = line[8],line[4]

    if key not in nets:
        nets[key] = set()
    nets[key].add( line[0] )

for k, v in nets.items():

    if len(v) <2:
        if k == ("connected_serverID", "ports") :
            #print(k, "single nets:", v)
            continue
        k_list.extend([k])

printout_k_list = [k_list[i][0] for i in range(len(k_list))]

seted_printout_klist=list(set(printout_k_list))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('improved_nets_singled_device.xlsx')
ports_analysis.loc[(seted_printout_klist[i] for i in range(len(seted_printout_klist)))].to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your criteria, there is only one instance of a server with multiple paths to a single subnet:

```
('Server_28', 'ge-8/0/0') redundant nets: {'NW8', 'NW9'}
```

Here's the code.  We just build up a dictionary where the key is (server,net) and the value is the set of ports for that combination.

```
data = """\
ServerID,NetworkID,Port name
Server_1,NW_1,ge-0/0/8
Server_2,NW_2,ge-0/0/5
Server_3,NW_3,Ethernet7/15
Server_4,NW4,ae4
Server_4,NW4,ge-2/2/0
Server_4,NW4,ge-2/2/1
Server_4,NW4,ge-2/2/2
Server_4,NW4,ge-2/3/0
Server_4,NW4,ge-2/3/1
Server_10,NW5,ae4
Server_10,NW5,ge-2/2/0
Server_10,NW5,ge-2/2/1
Server_10,NW5,ge-2/2/2
Server_10,NW5,ge-2/3/0
Server_10,NW5,ge-2/3/1
Server_16,NW6,ae5
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/3
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/4
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/5
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/3/2
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/3/3
Server_22,NW7,ae5
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/3
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/4
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/5
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/3/2
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/3/3
Server_28,NW8,ge-8/0/0
Server_28,NW9,ge-8/0/0
Server_30,NW10,ge-0/0/2
Server_30,NW11,ge-0/0/3
Server_32,NW12,ge8
Server_32,NW13,ge-0/0/2
Server_34,NW13,ge-0/0/3
Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/3
Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/4
Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/5
Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/6
Server_35,NW14,port-channel2
Server_35,NW15,xg16
Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/3
Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/4
Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/5
Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/6
Server_41,NW16,port-channel2
Server_41,NW17,xg16
Server_16,NW6,ae5
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/3
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/4
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/2/5
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/3/2
Server_16,NW6,ge-2/3/3 Server_22,NW7,ae5
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/3
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/4
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/2/5
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/3/2
Server_22,NW7,ge-2/3/3
Server_28,NW8,ge-8/0/0
Server_28,NW9,ge-8/0/0
Server_30,NW10,ge-0/0/2
Server_30,NW11,ge-0/0/3
Server_32,NW12,ge8
Server_32,NW13,ge-0/0/2
Server_34,NW13,ge-0/0/3
Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/3
Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/4
Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/5
Server_35,NW14,Ethernet1/6
Server_35,NW14,port-channel2
Server_35,NW15,xg16
Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/3
Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/4
Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/5
Server_41,NW16,Ethernet1/6
Server_41,NW16,port-channel2
Server_41,NW17,xg16"""

lines = data.splitlines()
nets = {}
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(',')
    key = parts[0],parts[2]
    if key not in nets:
        nets[key] = set()
    nets[key].add( parts[1] )

for k,v in nets.items():
    if len(v) < 2:
        continue
    print(k,"redundant nets:", v)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim Roberts. your code help me a lot in figuring out what I would like to do. I will upload  my code which is basically copying and pasting your code and adding some of mine next week.

Comment: If you use this code, don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted".